# Valid input for ArcPy raster to polygon in 10.1?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, python-2.7, raster-conversion

I'm experiencing some strange problems with this code starting from files with *.tif.tif to what seems should be *.tif.tif.shp according to the code. The code is not working because of the arcpy.RasterToPolygon_conversion Error 010157: Unable to open feature class. File name snowdepthN0001.tif.tif. Though the code fails, I get a single file in my output folder called snowdepthn0001.tif.shp (not sure why it's making the n lower case).

This is not the extension that I was expecting, and why would only this file turn up when there are 90 files in the input folder?

I have everything set-up to preference according to http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001200000008000000 but it seems there may be an extension problem.

I've tried both inside and outside of an ArcMap session.

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

env.workspace = r"C:\VMshared\small_example_valley8\SDpartINTRaster"
outFolder = r"C:\VMshared\small_example_valley8\SDpartINTshapefile"

for rasterFile in arcpy.ListRasters("*.tif"):
    oName, oExt = os.path.splitext(rasterFile + ".tif")
    outShape = os.path.join(outFolder, oName + ".shp")  
    arcpy.RasterToPolygon_conversion(rasterFile,outShape,"NO_SIMPLIFY","Value")

print "done"

#Executing: RasterToPolygon C:\VMshared\small_example_valley8\SDpartINTRaster\snowdepthN0001.tif.tif C:\VMshared\small_example_valley8\SDpartINTshapefile\snowdepthN0001.tif.tif.shp NO_SIMPLIFY Value
#Start Time: Sat May 16 15:12:54 2015
#ERROR 010157: Unable to open feature class C:\VMshared\small_example_valley8\SDpartINTshapefile\snowdepthN0001.tif.tif.
#Failed to execute (RasterToPolygon).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arcpy geoprocessing fails with file names that contain special characters like spaces or periods. I ran into this recently when I was able to use os.walk to read file names that contained periods, but arcpy.da.walk failed. I learned more about this problem in the help topic "[Validating table and field names in Python](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002z00000020000000)".

Please try your script again with no periods in the input or output file names. If you have a lot of input files, you may have to rename them first using os methods. Also, check to make sure that your input rasters are integer, which is what RasterToPolygon expects.

To make matters even more confusing, arcpy can read file names that contain dashes, but can not write them.

Comment: Thanks, I considered your advice, and it seems that it the conversion tool didn't like files that had more than one extension, e.g. *.tif.tif. I modified my ArcPy codes to give one extension at a time. I've got some integer shapefiles now! Thanks again.